# Why is rotationEffect moving vertically too?

Tags: ios, animation, swiftui

I have my animation for the rotation working beautifully, but the image is also moving vertically. Why?

```swift
struct SyncView: View {
    @State var isSyncing = false

    let animation: Animation = Animation.linear(duration: 2.0).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)

     var body: some View {
         VStack(spacing: 16) {
             HStack {
                 VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                     Text("Linked Device's Name")
                     Text("Updating (Last update: Oct 1, 2022)")
                         .font(.callout)
                         .foregroundColor(.gray)
                 }
                 Spacer()
                 Text(Image(systemName: "arrow.triangle.2.circlepath"))
                     .foregroundStyle(Color.yellow)
                     .font(.title)
                     .rotationEffect(Angle.degrees(isSyncing ? 360 : 0))
                     .animation(animation, value: isSyncing)
             }
         }
         .padding()
         .onAppear {
            isSyncing = true
         }
     }
}
```

[image: rotating arrows]

Comment: Why do you put an Image in a Text ❓

Comment: Irrelevant, however it's in a Text so it will size according to accessibility settings.

Comment: On what version of xCode/iOS are you running ? it is working as you expect on xCode 14.1 with simulator iOS 16.1 or iPhone 12 mini 16.1

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the frame of the `Text()` view to values that make up a square (e.g. 10 x 10). The animation might be trying to center an uneven frame of the image, thus the movement.

Comment: that didn't help

Answer (score 0):

This should solve it:

```
.onAppear{
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
     isSyncing = true
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**